# Function satisfying $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to [-2,2]$ non-trigonometric

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If there any non-trigonometric function $$f\colon \mathbb{R} \to [-2,2]$$

The following function $f(x) = 2\sin bx$ will satisfy the above criteria. This came up for discussion with my students.

Comment: $\min\{2,\max\{-2,g(x)\}\}$ for any function $g$

Comment: What about $2*\text{erf}(x)$

Comment: Using min, max the function can be restricted, but don't require restriction

Comment: I can use 2*signum(x) but it is not the solution

Comment: What do you mean not *the* solution?

Comment: Sorry, i did'nt new erf(x) function, i browsed it, thank you for given me info

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi $\,f(x)=0\,$ satisfies the conditions as written. If you meant to impose additional constraints on $f$ (surjective, maybe?) then you should make that clear in the question.

Comment: $f(x) = |x+1|-|x-1|$

Answer (score 4):

Try $f(x) = \dfrac{4x}{x^2+1}$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make up as many piece-wise defined functions as you'd like to. For example, let $f(x)=2x^3$ if $x \in [-1,1]$, and you can assign any value from $[-2,2]$ to the other values. For example, $f(x)=-2$ if $x<-1$ and $f(x)=2$ if $x>1$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use
$$
f(x)=\frac4{1+e^{-x}}-2.
$$
This is increasing, with $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=2$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}=-2$.

Comment: The OP seems to want $f$ surjective.

Answer (score 1):

For a non-trig periodic example, try a sawtooth function like $\; f(x) = 8 \cdot \big| x - \left\lfloor x+ 0.5 \right\rfloor \big| - 2\,$:

[image]